# ERROR: GROUP BY position 0 is not in select list , when using sql in Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe

So I'm not sure what is going on here, the spark Dataframe runs just fine and is created after the SQL query within Spark. However, if I ever go to show the dataframe, this error always shows up.

Here is the code:

```
e=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT "prod_MS", "application_status", COUNT(*) 
FROM test2
GROUP BY 1,2 """)
```

The part above worked fine.

```
e.select('count(1)').show()
```

This part always outputs this error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: GROUP BY position 0 is not in select list

Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Something to do with 0-based vs. 1-based series, I'd wager. If you `GROUP BY` column name instead of ordinal position it may work itself out.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Getting `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` would be unusual in Spark, especially with `GROUP BY`. This suggest you might be using some non-standard code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pyspark as no val:

```
e=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT prod_MS, application_status, COUNT(*) 
                     FROM test2
                    GROUP BY 1,2 """)
```

No quotes needed.

```
 e.select("count(1)").show()
```

Ran fine in 2.3.1 for pyspark and scala. may be an issue with 1.6? But you do not state the versions.